# How to configure multiple distributed transaction using bitronix in spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, transactions, microservices, distributed-transactions, bitronix

I am having one microservice with multiple datasource. i need to configure distributed transaction in that spring boot application.so, when transaction fail in one datasource it will rollback other DB transaction automatically.

So how can we configure bitronix into application or any other way to configure distributed transaction except atomikos?